# Как работать с ветками GIT и путями на сервере

Tags: git, nginx

Есть 2 ветки dev и prod. Для каждой ветки на сервере есть свои папки. Заливаю на сервер с помощью Bitbucket.

Как настроить пуши в ветки таким образом, что бы при пуше в dev заливалось по одному пути, а по пушу в prod по другому?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В Bitbucket есть такая функциональность - [pipelines](https://ru.atlassian.com/software/bitbucket/features/pipelines). С помощью нее вы можете настроить пуши в ветки, как вам необходимо.

[В документации](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/build-test-and-deploy-with-pipelines-792496469.html) достаточно содержательно описан весь процесс использования этого инструмента, [а тут](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/branch-workflows-856697482.html) показана работа с ветками.

Comment: спасибо человек!